# setUncaughtExceptionHandler not working in Maven project

Tags: java, maven, exception

I'm trying to handle uncaught exceptions on the main thread in my application so I can log them to a file (my app is a command line app which runs on an overnight job, so if something goes wrong I want admins to be able to easily see exceptions). I've reduced this to as simple a test case as I can.

Maven app generated with (as per the [getting started docs](https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/#How_do_I_make_my_first_Maven_project)):

```
   mvn -B archetype:generate \
      -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.maven.archetypes \
      -DgroupId=com.mycompany.app \
      -DartifactId=my-app
```

App.java:

```
package com.mycompany.app;

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Thread.currentThread().setUncaughtExceptionHandler(new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
            public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {
                System.out.println("Handled exception - let's log it!");
                // Logging code here
            }
        });

        System.out.println("Exception testing");
        throw new Exception("Catch and log me!");
    }

}
```

Running with `mvn exec:java` produces:

```
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.mycompany.app:my-app:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin is missing. @ line 20, column 15
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING] 
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building my-app 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:1.4.0:java (default-cli) @ my-app ---
Exception testing
[WARNING] 
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:293)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: Catch and log me!
    at com.mycompany.app.App.main(App.java:14)
    ... 6 more
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.493 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-10-26T10:57:00+00:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 8M/240M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.4.0:java (default-cli) on project my-app: An exception occured while executing the Java class. null: InvocationTargetException: Catch and log me! -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.4.0:java (default-cli) on project my-app: An exception occured while executing the Java class. null
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:216)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:862)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:286)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:197)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: An exception occured while executing the Java class. null
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo.execute(ExecJavaMojo.java:345)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:293)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: Catch and log me!
    at com.mycompany.app.App.main(App.java:14)
    ... 6 more
```

The same code run as a simple Java app works fine. App.java:

```
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Thread.currentThread().setUncaughtExceptionHandler(new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
            public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {
                System.out.println("Handled exception - let's log it!");
                // Logging code here
            }
        });

        System.out.println("Exception testing");
        throw new Exception("Catch and log me!");
    }

}
```

Running `javac App.java && java App` produces:

```
Exception testing
Handled exception - let's log it!
```

I suspect the advice to be given is "you shouldn't have any uncaught exceptions", but I'm not sure I guarantee that and am curious in any case as to the difference between the Maven and non-Maven results.

Comment: Does it work with `exec:exec` instead of `exec:java`? I suspect this has to do with the fact that `exec:java` run the Java app inside the same VM as the one Maven is running.

Comment: Hmm, I hadn't tried that. Just looked at the docs for `exec:exec` and it looks like I have to set up the classpath myself, which feels like it defeats the point of using Maven. I've just tried to use `exec:exec` but can't figure out how to pass the correct configuration. I'm getting "Error: Could not find or load main class com.mycompany.app.App" (plugin configuration set to `<executable>java</executable>
          <arguments>
            <argument>com.mycompany.app.App</argument>
          </arguments>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `JavaExecMojo` doesn't fork a new process. Instead it invokes the `main` method in the same thread as the mojo. So they must catch any exceptions thrown by the main method and emulate the jvm's behavior.

I think this is a bug in the maven exec plugin. Take a look at the source code of [ExecJavaMojo](http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/xref/org/codehaus/mojo/exec/ExecJavaMojo.html#L277).

The `JavaExecMojo` only uses

```
Thread.currentThread().getThreadGroup().uncaughtException( Thread.currentThread(), e );
```

to emulate the uncaught exception behavior. But this is not correct since the `uncaughtException` method of `ThreadGroup` is only invoked by the JVM if no uncaught exception handler is registered for the current thread. See the javadoc of [ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadGroup.html#uncaughtException(java.lang.Thread,%20java.lang.Throwable)).

> Called by the Java Virtual Machine when a thread in this thread group stops because of an uncaught exception, and the **thread does not have a specific Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler installed**.

I guess what the developers wanted to do is

```
try {
   .... 
   // invoke main method
} catch (Exception e) {
  Thread currentThread = Thread.currentThread();
  Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler ueh = currentThread.getUncaughtExceptionHandler();
  if (ueh == null) {
    currentThread.getThreadGroup().uncaughtException(currentThread, e);
  } else {
    ueh.uncaughtException(currentThread, e);
  }
}
```

This would emulate the JVM's behavior.

You can use the `defaultUncaughtExceptionHandler` as a quick fix.

```
Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
  public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {
    System.out.println("Handled exception - let's log it!");
    // Logging code here
  }
});
```

**EDIT**

> However, using defaultUncaughtExceptionHandler produces the same java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException.

You are right. They did another trick. They use an own `ThreadGroup` implementation. See [`IsolatedThreadGroup`](http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/xref/org/codehaus/mojo/exec/ExecJavaMojo.html#L356)

```
class IsolatedThreadGroup extends ThreadGroup {
     private Throwable uncaughtException; // synchronize access to this

     public IsolatedThreadGroup( String name ){
        super( name );
     }

    public void uncaughtException( Thread thread, Throwable throwable ) {
        if ( throwable instanceof ThreadDeath ) {
           return; // harmless
        }
        synchronized ( this ) {
            if ( uncaughtException == null ) {
                uncaughtException = throwable; // will be reported eventually
           }
        }
        getLog().warn( throwable );
    }
 }
```

The javadoc of `uncaughtException` enforces that

> The uncaughtException method of ThreadGroup does the following:
>
> - If this thread group has a parent thread group, the uncaughtException method of that parent is called with the same two arguments.
> - Otherwise, this method **checks to see if there is a default uncaught exception handler installed**, and if so, its uncaughtException method is called with the same two arguments.
> - Otherwise, this method determines if the Throwable argument is an instance of ThreadDeath. If so, nothing special is done. Otherwise, a message containing the thread's name, as returned from the thread's getName method, and a stack backtrace, using the Throwable's printStackTrace method, is printed to the standard error stream.

So their implementation is not api compliant. That's why the `defaultUncaughtExceptionHandler` doesn't work.

**Conclusion**

Don't use the `JavaExecMojo`. Use the `ExecMojo` instead. E.g.

```
 mvn exec:exec -Dexec.executable="java" -Dexec.workingdir="someDir" -Dexec.args="-cp target/classes"
```

Specify the plugin properties in the pom and you can use placeholders. E.g.

```
<workingdir>${basedir}</workingdir>
<args>-cp ${project.build.outputDirectory}</args>
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for the in-depth explanation. Makes sense. However, using `defaultUncaughtExceptionHandler` produces the same `java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException`.

Comment: @TomJenkins You're right. I took a deeper look at the source code and updated my answer.

Comment: Fantastic, thanks! Fortunately my app will be run in production outside of Maven (as a shaded jar); I can live with this in dev.